# Apply animation set to shape drawable

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-vectordrawable, android-shapedrawable

I have the following drawable red_dot.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval" >
    <solid android:color="#f00" />
    <size
        android:width="30dp"
        android:height="30dp"/>
</shape>
```

and the animation pulse.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:toAlpha="0.0"
        android:duration="1000"
        android:repeatMode="reverse"
        android:repeatCount="infinite" />
</set>
```

How can I apply the animation to the drawable **in an XML file**, e.g. red_dot_animated? If red_dot.xml was a vector file, the following would be possible (but it is not, since we have a shape)

```
<animated-vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:drawable="@drawable/red_dot_vector" >
     <target
         android:name="circle"
         android:animation="@anim/pulse" />
</animated-vector>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create a simple `View` and set `red_dot` as background and apply `animation` to that `view`

```
<View
  android:layout_width="30dp"
  android:layout_height="30dp"
  android:background="@drawable/red_dot"
  android:id="@+id/anime_view"
/>

View animeView = findViewById(R.id.anime_view);//Apply animation to animeView
```

Comment: Putting it in a drawable XML would have the advantage of directly using it for TextView's drawableLeft etc..